# is that possible to define different type of variable based on the input variable in c++?

Tags: c++, runtime

I am developing an algorithm in which I need to define one vector as real or complex depending on the input variable. The pseudo is like

```
void foo(bool is_real)
{
  if (is_real)
  {
    vector< double > v; 
  }
  else vector< complex > v;
}
```

Now I am writing two different version of algorithms, if is_real is true, I will use the algorithm for real case, otherwise, use the complex case. Actually, both algorithms are exact same except for the data type. So I google it and

```
#if is_real
  vector< double > v;
#else
  vector< complex > v;
#endif
```

But this code doesn't compile. I am using linux gnu c++ 4.7.2. I wonder if the macro only works for microsoft c++? I feel not comfortable since in my implementation the only difference will be data type, is there any way to select what type should be used in runtime? Thanks.

Comment: #ifdef is wrong. #if wont work because #if is during compile and is_real is not compile time constant

Comment: This is hard to do as you want it. It is best you use templates in some way like the answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the code is exactly the same, make it a template:

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename T>
    void foo() {
        vector<T> v;
        // blah
    }
}

void foo(bool is_real)
{
  if (is_real)
  {
    detail::foo<double>();
  }
  else detail::foo<complex>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ templates need to know their types at compile time.  In you first example the types are defined at run time which is not allowed in C++ which is a rather static language.  The second example uses compile time conditionals and so is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The macro is used by the Preprocessor it's a compile time instruction, You can't use it during run time. It assumes that you will define something and let the compiler know that you're working with real or complex numbers during compilation.

You can use templates (like suggested), but if you wish to initialize it in one place and then continue to work with the vectors you have several options -

1. Use inheritance and work with the vector of the base class
2. Have two vectors and only work with one (depending on the input)
3. Store your real numbers inside as complex numbers. It's a bit wasteful though.

Answer (score 0):

What your are trying to achieve with `is_real` can be done at compile time using `-Dis_real` option

At runtime you can have something like this :

```
template<typename T>
class MyAlgorithm
{
    public:

    MyAlgorithm(/*...*/ )
    {
        /*Your initialization routine */
    }

     /* copy constructor
     copy assignment operator */

    ~MyAlgorithm(/*...*/){ /*...Other deallocation stuffs...*/ }

    private:
        std::vector<T> vec;
};

int main ()
{

    MyAlgorithm<double> m;
    MyAlgorithm<std::complex<double> > n;

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's with the empty contructor and destructor?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes yeah, that's doesn't make sense but still

Comment: Sigh. Now you made it worse. The previous version's only problem was that it had some redundant code. Now it is actually broken because it violates the rule of three.